# JQuerymobile icons are wrong positioned

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, icons

Right now I am developing an app for iOs and Android with `JQM` and `Phonegap`. In front of the goal line I am facing a big problem and have no solution for that. Thats why I hope for some help.

I use the navbar e.g. with the JQM own icons. On my iPad 1(5.0) it looks great. Also in every simulator. Unfortunately not on the iPhone 4 and some Android devices with AMOLED display. There are the icons not correctly positioned.

The icons are there but dont fit the "holes". I already tried it with `JQM 1.1.0 RC1 and 1.0.1`! Same problem. The Design is made with the Themeroller. It must be something with the structured css file, but I am not sure what I can do.

Thanks for some help...

Edit: Screenshots...

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-13418328/icons.jpg.html

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-13418329/Navbar.jpg.html

Comment: Hi, I added 2 links for the screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PhoneGap issue but just differences in the way Android phones and iDevices render the HTML. We've had loads of issues with elements being lower/higher in one or the other device.

In order to get your icons to align correctly you will have to inspect the elements (load up the HTML in a browser) and find the right styles to override. I did this a while ago but can't remember which ones need to be overridden. They should be something like .ui-btn.